# How to get every job build details?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to retrieve every job build details using by Rest API in Jenkins.
I already I tried:

```
jenkins_url + /job/${job_name}/api/json?tree=builds[number,status,timestamp,id,result]
```

and

```
jenkins_url + /job/${job_name}/api/json?tree=jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

`https://ci.venmo.biz/api/json?tree=jobs[name,url,builds[number,status,timestamp,id,result],description]`

You can just put the names of the fields that you want to fetch. I've just added a few sample fields to show.

However, a word of caution, depending on the size of the response (number of jobs and builds), this might take a bit long to fetch all this data.

Depending on your use case, you could limit the amount of data fetched by using `{M,N}` filter to fetch only up to a fixed number of jobs or builds. For example:

`https://ci.venmo.biz/api/json?tree=jobs[name,url,builds[number,status,timestamp,id,result]{0,20},description]{0,10}`

would fetch only the first 20 builds each of the first 10 jobs.